# Index documents to Solr using sunburnt

Tags: python-2.7, solr, sunburnt

I want to index few csv files in solr and build search engine using sunburnt for solr,

```
from sunburnt import SolrInterface
si = sunburnt.SolrInterface("http://localhost:8985/solr/practice")
```

I get an error:

```
Key error: id
```

I am using python 2.7.11, Solr - 6.1, sunburnt 0.6

I found same post here in stackoverflow but it just had one answer and its link is not working now.

I am stuck. please guide me what should I do.
I have to build search engine which can search over multiple fields and over multiple files. I found that sunburnt is best for my case. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Are your providing an Id for your document or not ? In Solr schema.xml generally id is defined as a Unique Key and is a required parameter. Generally CSV files may have or not have an id field inside them . If not present , using DataImportHandler you can send a file with id . But for a quick fix solution , go to your schema.xml , look for a field declared as `id` .Remove `required=true` parameter from this field . Also look for a `uniqueKey` tag defined in your schema.xml generally defined at the top of a schema.xml file . Remove it completely and try again by restarting the server. If this error resolves, you can further spend your time exploring how to send id as a parameter to your documents . An id for a document is required to uniquely identify it , otherwise same document could be indexed by Solr multiple times, there by creating duplicate documents in the index, which is not desirable at all . Hope this helps :)

Comment: id is present in schema as well as in my csv file but I am getting this error while making connection with solr through sunburnt. I guess it s bug as one of the post but dont knoe how to resolve it